# Как узнать размер результата запроса в JPA?

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate, jpa

Что-то совсем запутался с этим JPA(( Есть запрос

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Movie> movieCriteria = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Movie.class);

    Root<Movie> movieRoot = movieCriteria.from(Movie.class);

    movieCriteria.select(movieRoot);
    movieCriteria.distinct(true);

    Join<Movie, Country> countriesJoin = movieRoot.join(Movie_.country);

    Join<Movie, Genre> genresJoin = movieRoot.join(Movie_.genre);

    movieCriteria.where(cb.equal(genresJoin.get(Genre_.id), genreId), cb.equal(countriesJoin.get(Country_.id), countryId));

    movieCriteria.orderBy(cb.asc(movieRoot.get(sort)));
```

Как можно грамотно получить размер результата?

Пытался добавить в конце

```
    CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);

    Root<Movie> mw = cq.from(movieCriteria.getResultType());

    cq.select(cb.count(mw));
    return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
```

Но возвращается вся таблица(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял Вы хотите получить количество строк по условию?

Можно внести исправления в первый запрос:

```
//заменяем тип
CriteriaQuery<Long> movieCriteria = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
...
//получаем count
movieCriteria.select(cb.count(movieRoot));
...
//убираем orderBy
...
//получаем результат
Long count = entityManager.createQuery(movieCriteria).getSingleResult();
```

Либо дополнить второй условиями:

```
cq.where(.... //аналогично с join-ами
```

Если требуется как подсчет количества записей, так и выборка, и при этом нужно избежать дублирования кода, то можно вынести общую часть (создание условий и связей) в отдельные методы.

```
cq.where(createMovieConditions(movieRoot));
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Часа 3 не мог с этим разобраться, вроде через обычные запросы sql всё просто и легко, а через эти CriteriaQuery у меня мозг ломается, никак не могу суть их уловить. Насчёт отдельного метода. Вы предлагаете создать отдельный метод который будет возвращать набор предикатов для where? Правильно ли делать такие методы в этом же DAO?

Comment: @Socket123 Пожалуйста! Да, вспомогательный метод для создания предикатов. Насколько я знаю, `private` методы, которые сокращают код, никогда никому не мешали.